# How do i open jar files created by netbeans in ubuntu?

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, netbeans

I'm trying to execute a jar file developed in Apache NetBeans 11.2 in Ubuntu 19.10 by double clicking it or launching via terminal (java -jar filename.jar) but it doesn't launch - nothing happens. It is a simple program that manages the daily work routine of an employee, it was programmed with Jframe GUI. And the program has I / O operations. I already made the jar file  executable and i have  JRE installed on Ubuntu. I have discovered that the manifest file is empty and it doesn't contain the main class, instead it has: "Manifest-Version: 1.0 X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build"
It says that the main-class will be added automatically by build but it is not added. I developed another program (a game) in Intellij Idea IDE, whose the jar file has a manifest file containing the main class and even with the fact that i have used Liberica JDK in development the Open JRE associated with jar files works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to describe what method or methods you are using to attempt to open the file, and exactly what happens--including any error messages. In particular, if you are running one or more commands in a terminal, please include the complete and exact text of those commands as well as their full output.

Comment: you tried the "-cp" option? do you have a main()?

Comment: Yes i have a main() class and what is "-cp" option?

Comment: In the previous revision of question you mentioned that you developed the jar using Liberica JDK but running using OpenJDK13. Since LibericaJDK and OpenJDK are little bit different so it is not necessary that jar build using one would definitely run on other. If you have the source code, try building jar using OpenJDK and then run. Also, please mention what does the jar actually do. It might happen it executed but produced no output.

Comment: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. These were the error present in the build process. Thought, that was not the problem either the manifest file. I fixed the problem in the packing set-ups - properties of the project - It is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you must create launcher on desktop, with

> /path /to /bin /file.jar

Also, you can debug your file with idea studio